# Index multiple columns of the same table for Context Full-Text Search?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I have a table with 3 columns that need to be enabled for full-text searching via Oracle APEX Application. How can I create an index for all three columns so that they can all be searched?

Currently I have context indexing on one column (STOP_NAME):

```
DECLARE

  l_query VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

  l_query:= 
   'select 
    "BUS_STOP_ID",
    "STOP_NAME",
    "DESC_NOTES",
    "BUS_NUMBERS",
    "LOCATION"
    from   "BUS_STOPS" ';

  IF v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') IS NOT NULL THEN
    l_query := l_query||' '||'
    where 
    (   
     CONTAINS(STOP_NAME, ''$'|| v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') ||''') > 0
    )
   ';
  END IF;

  RETURN l_query;

END;
```

But how can I create an index that uses three columns (stop_name, desc_notes, bus_numbers) for the text search? I tried using standard index creating using 3 columns but it didn't work:

```
CREATE INDEX bus_stops_ctx_idx
ON bus_stops (stop_name, bus_numbers, desc_notes)
INDEXTYPE IS ctxsys.context;
```

Comment: SQL injection alert!  Try this instead: `CONTAINS(STOP_NAME, ''$''|| :P2_REPORT_SEARCH) > 0`

Comment: Can you please explain how this prevents sql injection and also how the $ does not prevent values from being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First step was to create an indexing preference:

```
BEGIN
ctx_ddl.create_preference('my_multi_idx', 'MULTI_COLUMN_DATASTORE');
ctx_ddl.set_attribute('my_multi_idx', 'COLUMNS', 'stop_name, desc_notes, bus_numbers');
END;
```

Followed by creating the index itself using the previously set preferences:

```
CREATE INDEX bus_stops_ctx_idx
ON bus_stops(stop_name)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
PARAMETERS ('DATASTORE my_multi_idx SYNC ( ON COMMIT )');
```

Comment: When I try this my query returns rows from my second column but not my first column, even though the first column is the first parameter of contains

Comment: select * from xxpeople where contains(first_name, 'lin AND merwe') > 0 order  by first_name, last_name;

Comment: Strangely enough without the AND it does search on the first column.